# Событие, реагирующее на изменение содержимого ячейки DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Как правильно подписать на событие изменения статуса CheckBox в столбце DataGridView?

Нашел события CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged и CellValueChanged, написано что нужно запускать первое и через него как-то выходить
на второе, вроде бы описал но при компиляции не реагирует. Может, неверно подписался на Designer?

```
private void dataGridViewPrices_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridViewPrices.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        { dataGridViewPrices.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit); }
    }

    private void dataGridViewPrices_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int intNumColumnDeleteAttribute = 0;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == intNumColumnDeleteAttribute)
        {
            if ((bool)dataGridViewPrices[intNumColumnDeleteAttribute, e.RowIndex].Value == true)
            { dataGridViewPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; }
            else { dataGridViewPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код о котором идёт речь. Так отвечающим будет проще указать что и как исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня ваш код работает (строки окрашиваются при установленном чекбоксе), единственное что добавил - это проверку индексов в начале метода `dataGridViewPrices_CellValueChanged` `if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;`

Comment: Да я и сам уже разобрался. Оказывается неверно подписан на события был.